# Comparison between different versions of chef cookbooks using python

Tags: chef-infra

I have 2 version of chef cookbooks let's say 'release/x' and 'release/y'.
I wanted to compare between these 2 versions using python script.
Could someone please let me know, how can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chef version numbers are required to be three integers (`x.y.z`) so even just a normal tuple comparison is probably fine. But the normal way is `from pkg_resources import parse_version` and that should also work.

Comment: Let's assume versions are 'release/1.1.0' & 'release/2.1.0'.

Comment: They literally cannot be. You could have git tags or branches like that, but Chef cookbook versions _must_ match the format I mentioned.